# App receiving low memory warning but only has 5.7MB of live bytes

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, memory-management, instruments

My app has been receiving a low memory warning with a repetitive action and eventually crashes.  When I profiled in instruments, I only see 5.7 MB of living bytes at crash.  (The crash shows no traceback, no errors, etc.  It just terminates, which is indicative of a memory crash.)

Why is my app crashing with such a low memory footprint??  I've been testing on iOS 5.1 on iPad 1.

[image: Instruments screenshot]

**Edit:**
I was able to fix the crashing.  It was due to an extra retain call on an object that has 3 `UIImages` as properties.  An accumulation of these objects was causing the memory warning and crashing.

However, the question still remains: why did Instruments show that there were only 5.7MB of live bytes?  Could this be due to `UIImage's` automatic caching?

Comment: Crash may not due to low memory. What is the crash error?

Comment: Good thought, but there is no traceback or error given.  It just terminates.  (I've added this to the question in an edit.)

Comment: how about type `bt` ( then press Enter ) in Xcode console ? what does compiler say ?

Comment: It doesn't let me enter anything in console.  There's no automatic breakpoint before terminating.

Comment: Do you use a lot of `[UIImage imageNamed:]`?

Comment: I use a lot of [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:] and [UIImage imageWithCGImage:]

Comment: It seems that you should really identify the precise source of the crash. See [My App Crashed, Now What?](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1)

Comment: can you show some code where you use them

Comment: another think is if in instrument you add with the button library the "memory Monitor" tool you can see also when e how your memory go down

Comment: Do you currently have any problems with abandoned memory? Have you done some heapshot analysis? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/developertools/conceptual/instrumentsuserguide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html

Comment: I'd be interested to see what the "Leaks" instrument gives you. Some things I'm reading say that `CGBitmapContextGetData` allocates bitmap data but never frees it (Despite the fact that it's a 'Get'), so you may be dealing with a memory leak.

Comment: @daltonclaybrook : Thanks for the idea, but that can't be the issue.  I've gutted this method to see how simple I can get it and still cause crashing.  See Edit #2

Comment: This can be an issue in the memory tool itself because a similar thing happened to me when a NSMutableString kept growing due to a bug in my logic. All I saw was memory warnings and the application crashes after a few but the memory usage at the time was only ~8 MB. The symptoms were the memory quickly grew to ~8 MB, kept there for about a few minutes and warnings came. After some time, the application hang and crash, make any sense ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any obvious leaks in the code you've posted, but if you're just trying to redraw the image (presumably to force immediate decompression) then that's an amazingly complicated way to do it. Just do this:

```
- (void)loadImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, image.scale);
    [image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    self.someImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Hopefully that will fix whatever leak you are seeing.

Comment: ya there was a lot of pixel by pixel manipulation in the middle of that method that I gutted out for simplicity.  when i commented out that code, the same problem still persisted, so i figured it wasn't relevant to show.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set NSZombieEnabled to YES in the environment variables?

When zombies are enabled memory is never really freed but retained in a zombie pool for debugging references to invalid pointers.